# Cocos Creator Performance issue

Tags: javascript, html, performance, retina, cocoscreator

I'm using Cocos Creator to develop a new HTML game but the performance in my Macbook Pro Retina (2015) display is really bad. I started a new project to do some tests and i just created the Canvas and a label that says "Hello World". The problema is that just with those two elements in screen, the FPS in my macbook's display is lower that 30.

If I test the same compiled code in a full HD screen the FPS is stable at 60.

I don't know if the problem is related to the Cocos generated code or if there are any property that i should change in HTML/JS for retina displays.

Thanks!